# Kendo Autocomplete not working after upgrading the kendo version

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

We have an ASP.NET MVC application using KendoUI jQuery components. The KendoUI version used is 2014.3.1411 and every thing works very good here.

Recently I have been assigned to upgrade the KendoUI version to 2022.3.1109 and after Kendo upgrade, all the Kendo controls are working fine except for autocomplete.

Below is the code which is used for Autocomplete which works well with old Kendo reference and now giving console errors.

```
<div class="item">
        <div class="claim-info-description">
            <label>Provider<span class="icon icon-question-mark help-text" title="Enter the Provider Name who hosted the course.  You can search the PMI Education Provider Directory or type in a third-party provider name."></span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="claim-info-data">
            @(Html.Kendo().AutoCompleteFor(m => m.ProviderName)
                    .Name("ProviderName")
                    .IgnoreCase(true)
                    .DataTextField("ProviderName")
                    .MinLength(3)
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { placeholder = "Provider Name or ID", required = "required", validationmessage = "Enter Provider Name or ID", data_maxprovidertextlength = "150", data_maxprovidertextlength_msg = "Text must be less than 150 characters.", data_providernospaces_msg = "A value must be entered for the Provider." })
                    .DataSource(source =>
                    {
                        source.Read(read =>
                        {
                            read.Action("ProviderAutoComplete", "Search")
                                .Data("onProviderData");
                        })
                        .ServerFiltering(true);
                    })
                    .HeaderTemplate("<span class=\"k-state-default list-header\"><span>Provider #</span><em>Name</em></span>")
                    .Template("<span class=\"k-state-default\"><span>#: data.ProviderNumber #</span><em>#:data.ProviderName # </em></span>")
                    .Events(e =>
                    {
                        e.Filtering("clearProviderValues").Select("onProviderSelect");
                    })
            )
            <span class="invalid-msg-placeholder"><span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="ProviderName"></span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the error getting for autocomplete after the Kendo update:

[image]

Please suggest and help me fix this issue as I'm not understanding what's wrong here.

Comment: The legacy **ASP.NET** - or the newer ASP.NET **Core** ? You've tagged both - they're not the exact same ...

Comment: Edited, Using Asp.Net core and the nuget  Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.9 is recently updated by me from 5.2.7. Also upgraded the target framework from 4.7.2 to 4.8.

Comment: But target framework 4.8 is the "old", legacy, full .NET Framework - ***NOT*** .NET Core !

Comment: Have you checked/verified that all your kendo css/js, jquery js files are the appropriate versions to match up with the requirements of your new Kendo version? Particularly on the pages with the Autocomplete controls that don't work.

Comment: Yes, I already verified . Issue is happening on those pages where autocomplete is used. All the other Kendo controls are working fine. Actually the jquery generated for autocomplete is throwing error as Invalid template. The control will work properly if the kendo output html templates for autocomplete will work fine which actually working fine once i change the reference back to old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your header template does indeed look invalid. I've expanded it to make it easier to read:

```
<span class="k-state-default list-header">
  <span>Provider #</span>
  <em>Name</em>
</span>
```

My experience with kendo doesn't go back as far as 2014 but I know that the current templating rules mean that the number of # symbols should be even and there is only one. I think it should become this:

```
<span class="k-state-default list-header">
  <span>#:Provider #</span>
  <em>Name</em>
</span>
```

Hence change your code to this and let us know if that helps:

```
.HeaderTemplate("<span class=\"k-state-default list-header\"><span>#:Provider #</span><em>Name</em></span>")
```

Comment: After this change, getting  Uncaught ReferenceError: Provider is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (kendo.all.js:312399:21)

Comment: Give #: data.Provider# a try. You don't usually need the data prefix but your other template uses it so maybe it is necessary in your setup.